# Docker / terminal command in a juypter notebook cell

Tags: python, docker, subprocess

I am trying to run this docker function in Juypter Notebook:

```
subprocess.run(["docker", "run", "--rm", "-t", "--name", "stream", "-v", "/home/benson/OCR_project:/user-data/", "--user", "id -u:`id -g`", "-e", f"LICENSE_KEY={license_key}", "-e", f"TOKEN={token}", "platerecognizer/alpr-stream"])
```

Which is from here: https://platerecognizer.com/

I am trying to do this in a while loop, but when I try and run the subprocess, even just in a Juypter notebook cell outside of the while loop to check its working, I get this error:​

```
CompletedProcess(args=['docker', 'run', '--rm', '-t', '--name', 'stream', '-v', '/home/benson/OCR_project:/user-data/', '--user', 'id -u:`id -g`', '-e', 'LICENSE_KEY=sB6WCDvshT', '-e', 'TOKEN=80cc7ff865e421cde42a2df9ae165f5f5482b5a5', 'platerecognizer/alpr-stream'], returncode=125)
```

125 means error, and nothing runs, but I was looking for some guidance. I'm not very fluent with running terminal commands in Juypter and a while loop.

Comment: Please post the result of the stdout and stderr capture via `subprocess.run(["docker", "run", "--rm", "-t", "--name", "stream", "-v", "/home/benson/OCR_project:/user-data/", "--user", "id -u:`id -g`", "-e", f"LICENSE_KEY={license_key}", "-e", f"TOKEN={token}", "platerecognizer/alpr-stream"], capture_output=True)`

Comment: Run `type docker` in your Terminal and then use its **full** path in your `subprocess()` call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is with:

```
"--user", "id -u:`id -g`"
```

This looks like an attempt to retrieve your UID and GID using the commands `id -u` and `id -g`. The `id -g` is enclosed in back ticks, which are used to tell the shell to execute the enclosed command and then replace the command with the command's output. For this to work, the `id -u` would also need to be enclosed in back ticks. However you are not executing the command from a shell. You can use two more python commands to get the UID and GID and then pass them to the `subprocess.run(...)` command:

```
import os
import subprocess

gid = os.getegid()
uid = os.geteuid()

subprocess.run(["docker", "run", "--rm", "-t", "--name", "stream", "-v", "/home/benson/OCR_project:/user-data/", "--user", f"{uid}:{gid}", "-e", f"LICENSE_KEY={license_key}", "-e", f"TOKEN={token}", "platerecognizer/alpr-stream"])
```

Comment: Well spotted! And good alternative way of getting values.

Comment: Hey WIll (and Mark). Many thanks for the tips here.

I tried running this:

gid = os.getegid() [prints 1028]
uid = os.geteuid() [prints 1027]


I get this error: returncode=0, stdout=b'INFO:root:Plate Recognizer Stream v1.36.0\r\nERROR:root:/user-data/.stream is not writable.\r\nERROR:root:\r\n[STR0018]\r\nTo best help us help you, please include the following when you contact us.\r\n- Steps to reproduce the behavior.\r\n- Screenshot of the error or command output.\r\n\r\n', stderr=b'')

Comment: In the host OS, does `/home/benson/OCR_project` exist? And do you have write access? `mkdir -p /home/benson/OCR_project && chmod -R 755 /home/benson/OCR_project` has a good chance of resolving the error. Could also be a result of being out of disk space.